# Use Autofac to inject a list of specified keyed/named items into component

Tags: c#, autofac

I have an interface `IService` of which I have multiple implementations. I have a class `ConsumerClass` which takes an `IEnumerable<IService>` as a parameter. I realise that if I just leave it, Autofac will automatically create the enumerable and fill it with all registered service implementations, but I'd like to specify which implementations are injected.

A reason for this would be that `ConsumerClass` might have one implementation, but be registered twice in Autofac - the only difference being what's injected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out accidentally. Basically, the ResolvedParameter constructor second parameter returns result to fill it, therefore I can create the list myself. It's not perfect but it works:

```
builder.RegisterType<Component>().WithParameters(new[] {
    new ResolvedParameter((p,c) => p.Name == "serv",(p,c) => 
        new List<ITerry>
        {
            c.ResolveKeyed<IService>(Services.Svc1),
            c.ResolveKeyed<IService>(Services.Svc3),
            c.ResolveKeyed<IService>(Services.Svc8),
        })
});
```